# Known-bad triage audit generated from question deleted by now-deleted user

Tags: support, review-audits, disputed-review-audits, triage

It looks like https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/9480690 * mistakenly assumed that, because the question was deleted by a single user, and because that user was not the *current* post owner, therefore the post must have been deleted by a diamond while downvoted, and thus an excellent choice for a known-bad audit.

I think you can make a decent case that the question should be closed, of course, so it's not really the end of the world, but that seems like shaky ground to use for audit generation. Instead, check to see if the user self-deleted in a more reliable way, and if so, don't use it.

I considered the possibility that the user got deleted by a moderator, but since in any case the question was obviously deleted by them before the user was deleted, I don't think that matters, either way.

<sub>**I passed the audit, by the way.*</sub>

Comment: I'm torn... On the one hand, this is a bug: the question shouldn't have been picked by the current audit criteria. On the other hand, that'd make a great audit; maybe the audit criteria *should* be picking questions like that... BTW: check the revision history & you'll see the real reason why that got picked as an audit.

Comment: @Shog9: I know this is a very funky case. I think if you deliberately included the weird corner case where a user self-deleted before being banhammered, that would be fine, but otherwise, self-deletion after downvotes (even if the account is later voluntarily deleted) really isn't clear-cut enough in general to make for good audits.

Comment: It wasn't picked because he self-deleted; it was picked because he replaced his question with a vulgar rant. If a moderator hadn't rolled back the edit, this would've been a glaringly obvious audit.

Comment: @Shog9: Ohhh, interesting. So it would have to be revision-specific. That's even more unfortunate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've added checks to ensure that only posts which were actually deleted by the system in response to spam flags are used for this purpose - this should avoid situations where posts deleted for other reasons (for instance, due to the destruction of their author's account) are used.

See: [NSFW triage review audit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362493/nsfw-triage-review-audit/377864#377864)