# NSFW triage review audit

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, review-audits

I sometimes go through some of the review queues at work when I have some time left over.

Now I ran into the following review and I was a bit shocked.

[Review - Warning: Image is no longer available!](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/18621910)

Seeing that this was a test, to find out if I am still paying attention and not just clicking through, I was shocked when I clicked the link. If one of my coworkers or boss etc saw what I was looking at I would have had some explaining to do.

Why does content like that not get cleared instantly instead of being put into a review queue as a test?

Edit:

the question got marked as duplicate of:
[Should questions destroyed as being offensive be used as review audits?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333182/should-questions-destroyed-as-being-offensive-be-used-as-review-audits)

I do not consider this solving my question, seeing that this feature or problem has not been solved still up to this day. Seeing that these sorts of audits still pop-up.

These types of audits are totally unnecessary, they should be deleted or removed permanently and not come back into the review queues.

Comment: well.. reviewing is about filtering out garbage. isnt it? what if that was an actual post and not an audit?

Comment: Why do reviews at work?

Comment: @SurajRao I understand that reviewing is about filtering out garbage, but this content should only be reviewed once. I consider this the worst kind of "Garbage". If the message was already deleted, it should not be put back into any review queues. The tests can also be done with less inappropriate content.

Comment: @Pang I consider this review inappropriate no matter where I am. Review's dont have to be this harsh to make it a test.

Comment: I always thought posts flagged as r/a won't show up as audits, but apparently this isn't the case here (or it was not flagged as such).

Comment: Pretty sure it was, if you go to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48364076 (10k+) you'll see it.

Comment: The revision history is interesting as well: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48364076/revisions

Comment: I just think that these sorts of reviews should be flagged so they don't go into a audits. I have no idea if there is a system for this or not but if there isn't it should be something to think about adding to it.

Comment: Or better yet, looking at https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48364076/timeline it's clear that even this is catching some people in audits. [Someone](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/18611529) figured it just required some editing.

Comment: @ivarni: "inlining images is always helpful!" `</s>`

Comment: @Granny Anyway, since there's no way of flagging that (that I know of) you're in the right place. Someone will hopefully come along and fix it.

Comment: A simple improvement in my eyes would be to make images hidden by default until maybe the post is seen as okay based on criteria (say: it has a score > 0). You then have to click something to make them visible. At least then it's in your own hands to make them visible and you can review the nature of the content first.

Comment: I've already voiced my opinion about the atrociousness of the audit review process. Everyone seemed to be OK with it so far. Good luck getting any change here. I was told "it was worse before" and then downvoted into oblivion. Apparently "worse before" means we can't improve it anymore.

Comment: reopened due to the age of the duplicate, and I'm writing an answer now. Going to status-review this shortly. Hang tight folks :)

Comment: Filtering NSFW content is part of moderating. Why are you moderating when at work anyway? You'd have had some explaining to do if they caught you moderating SO posts

Comment: Folks, let's not blame the person that this happened to? :)  Yeah, there's a part of this where one could say _you see strange stuff when you moderate content_, but there's also another part that says _we're some of the smartest people ever gathered in one place and we should probably treat this as a problem and work on it because we can_ - so let's think on that side of it, if you will :)

Comment: Related https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238647/213575

Comment: @Emobe What I do with my free time during work is my own decision. So they would not make a problem about me being on stack-overflow moderating and what not. What they would have a problem with is the fact that i had a naked woman and a guy having sex on my screen. Because as you might know that is very inappropriate for the workplace.

Comment: I wouldn't put it past some people to be leaving these types of images with the specific intention of getting (re)viewers into trouble at work...

Comment: If something is NSFW I don't want to see it at home either.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

I'm sorry that happened to you. That wasn't what we'd want for anyone that was giving us a piece of their time, especially at work, or using a family computer in a communal space, especially if it might have triggered something as or more unpleasant than the image itself.

I'm reopening this because it's a couple of years after the last time this came up, and circumstances surrounding it might have changed. Let me start off with a tad bit of background, and I'll try to keep brevity in mind.

It's hard to get folks to select the flag that best fits what they've seen. Some flagged that as spam, some flagged it as offensive, some flagged it as very low quality. All of those flags apply, but *offensive* is what really needed to stand out there.

Review generates audits automatically based on what the system perceives to be consensus that something is resoundingly *good* or *bad* in the context of any given review. Because folks flag stuff so strangely, the system treats spam / offensive / very low quality as *essentially* the same kind of signal ("bad"). When we last ran some numbers on looking at what would happen if we dropped anything that had offensive attached to it from audits, the impact would have been enough to be considered significant.

That was a few years back, so we're going to look at it again, and I'm going to put this as being under review.

#### Now, until then --

If you see something that has *barely* more than a link to something (especially an image) - it's game over, the post is of sufficiently low quality that it should be removed, there's no reason to even *follow* the link, especially at work.

#### Concluding:

We'll do one of two things:

- Drop posts that have abuse flags as review candidates
- If that's just not possible, put a *very* clear warning that any links might not have been vetted, and might not be safe for a family or work environment (whether we show this all the time, or similarly to how we do the *be careful, this could be SPAM* notice will remain to be seen depending on numbers).

In any event, I'm sorry that happened to you, and I'll update on what we come up with as a fix, even if it's short-term.

Comment: This is why I'm personally not a fan of abuse flags being used on posts that don't contain shocking or hate content, but instead simply "abuse" the Q&A functionality, e.g. by posting deliberate nonsense text. The kind of stuff that belongs in audits possibly more than anything else.

Comment: Rude or offensive flags are handled exclusively by elected mods (or auto-deleted if there are enough flags), right? So I'd argue we shouldn't be showing content identified as such to the average user regardless. After all, such flags describe the content as something a reasonable person would find inappropriate. It's not just about links, text can be found similarly offensive (and we can't exactly prevent that being seen if we're trying to use it as an audit).

Comment: @Dukeling: They are, if they don't accumulate on their own before we get to them.

Comment: I was under the impression that posts with a helpful r/a   flag were already supposed to be dropped from audits. In fact - I'm fairly sure I recall similar questions before where staff have said it shouldn't happen and stuff was changed (might have been animuson/shog). This isn't just some strange code regression that's happened is it? :p

Comment: @JonClements I can only remember _talking_ about dropping anything with abuse attached to it and getting a little depressed to learn that people still use it more inappropriately than correctly, but I don't know if we actually pushed the change after that since the impact seemed like it would be less than trivial. I pinged Shog and we'll figure it out today and either get the regression fixed or put something else in place.

Comment: @BoltClock [Shog seems to encourage abusive flags on nonsense](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/234035/165773) (frankly I won't mind if audits stop getting flagged-nonsense because there are plenty other kinds of known-bad examples to catch robo reviewers)

Comment: @gnat: Doesn't mean I can't disagree.

Comment: sure you can but your reasons for disagreement look rather weak. "Oh these make perfect audits"... as if other kind audits (link-only answers, thank-you dumps and questions stuffed into answer field) would fail to catch robo reviewers

Comment: ??? Are we moving goalposts and dropping @mentions now?

Comment: me, I am trying to keep the goalpost at where it started: the idea to drop posts flagged as abusive off the audits. Also I am trying to prevent moving goalposts in the direction of the (wrong) idea of prohibiting abusive flags for nonsense posts :) @BoltClock

Comment: I should stick to playing board games...

Comment: I agree with @BoltClock, using VLQ for gibberish and nonsense makes much more sense than abusive, in all respects other than the penalty, but IMO that should be left up to mods to determine whether it was likely to be a cat or if this user has a habit of trolling.

Comment: @TinyGiant while nice in theory this approach won't scale (it probably worked fine in the past, like 5-6 years ago)

Comment: @gnat there are a multitude of solutions to that problem, though I won't delve into that in the comments section of a tangentially related meta post

Comment: @gnat: It does seem to me that we *should* have separate flag options for "this is nonsense / gibberish" and "this is toxic / NSFW and nobody should have to look at it", because those two kinds of posts need different handling: in particular, the former is not urgent, can be handled by review and even makes a decent audit, whereas the latter should be nuked ASAP, hidden by default even from 10k rep users and never, ever used as an audit. [...]

Comment: [...] Now, we can argue about what those flags should be called, and how exactly the system should handle them, but it seems to me that the existing VLQ and abusive flags would at least be pretty close, if only the flag dialog provided clearer instructions on how to choose between them. (And, having said that, I'm the first to admit that I just recently went against my own advice above and flagged [a nonsense post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48411910) as abusive. But I only did that because I checked meta and found Shog's post saying that I should.)

Comment: @IlmariKaronen dedicated nonsense flag would probably be too noisy, if you try walking in the shoes of a regular inexperienced flagger. You'd get like, 10 nonsense flags for Java answers to Javascript question vs one flag for "asdfgasdfg"

Comment: @gnat we have a dedicated nonsense flag: VLQ

Comment: @TinyGiant history has shown that while correct in theory it somehow didn't work very well in practice. Personally I find it difficult to understand because when abusive flag was forbidden for nonsense posts I used VLQ without any problems. However it looks like this wasn't so for too many other flaggers (not that I complain though)

Comment: @gnat as far as I can tell it has never been forbiddden to use the VLQ flag for absolute unarguable garbage (gibberish and nonsense qualify just like non english posts). It has just been _encouraged_ to use an r/a flag mainly because 6 flags gets it gone quick while VLQ flags require more revew and take longer.

Comment: @TinyGiant sure, now ask yourself a question, why did they decide to encourage giving more power for content deletion to regular users with mere 15 rep (required for flagging). For many years before things worked fairly well without that, what could possibly have changed that made them want more power for deletions

Comment: @gnat are you trying to imply that the only possible way to get the same effect is to lump these posts in with r/a? If so I think you're missing the point. If not I don't really understand what point you're trying to make.

Answer (score 42):

As of today (December 14, 2018), any validated "rude or abusive" flags on a post will make that post ineligible for use as a "known-bad" audit in either the Triage or the Low Quality review queues.

Additionally, I've added checks to ensure that only posts which were actually *deleted by the system* in response to spam flags are used for this purpose - this should avoid situations where posts deleted for other reasons (for instance, due to the destruction of their author's account) are used. Such posts are often offensive, confusing or otherwise misleading in the context of an audit, and thus relying on confirmed spam should avoid some unnecessary distress for reviewers here.

#### See also: [Should this audit be removed?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/350236/should-this-audit-be-removed)

Comment: excellent news.

Comment: So, does this separate spam and R/A flags?

Comment: They've always been separate, @ekons. They're just treated as equivalent in many places; this is no longer one of those places.

Comment: Why not use NAA/VLQ in the low quality queue? At the end of the day, these are the kind of post that enter on the queue, no?

Comment: You've [asked that before](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/374043/lets-stop-people-getting-confused-and-failing-by-audits-and-remove-the-worse/374048#374048), @braiam

Comment: BTW, I've asked a FR about this https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238647/213575

Comment: There's a [feature request on Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/343436/exclude-posts-with-valid-rude-or-abusive-flags-from-appearing-as-review-audits) asking that this same exclusion be implemented on audits in all the other review queues as well, not just the two here. However, a staff member [commented](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/1185505) that the request was more involved than initially suspected, and marked it as deferred. In your opinion, why is this more difficult to implement on other review queues than the ones here?

Comment: No idea, @gparyani. My guess would be, the request itself isn't substantially different but rather the logic that would need to be changed is: Triage and LQ both have unique logic for generating audits, and both are significantly different from that used for First Posts and Late Answers. IOW, would require careful modifications to the queries, not just applying the same patch already applied to the two queues mentioned.