# I didn't pass a review audit

Tags: discussion, support, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50459871/is-there-anything-like-a-cookbook-for-perl-6 was brought up on the Triage queue (https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/20053981).

I naturally flagged it as opinion-based; and was told that I failed an audit and that the question is OK. ... but I thought we weren't supposed to ask for reading material suggestions on SO? There's even a comment under the question to that effect, so I'm not alone in thinking this should be closed.

---

(note: This has been flagged as a duplicate, and I don't mind it being closed... but in the duplicate suggested it does say that it's a good thing to create questions like these to bring bad audit questions to the attention of the community - so if it is closed, can someone suggest another way to do it?)

Comment: Nitpick, but there is a "recommendation" close reason, that should've been selected, instead of POB. Not that it changes anything, this does indeed seem like a bad audit

Comment: @Patrice thanks, took me a while to find that hidden away in the options!

Comment: Since that question has received down-votes now, it will no longer be presented as an audit. Problem solved. :)

Comment: can't have a bad audit if we just delete the question from history.

Comment: Be sure to make a note of this meta question in case you run into a ban later. A moderator can undo a ban if (a) bad audit(s) caused it.

Comment: @BSMP Unfortunately there's far too many audits that are low quality. Personally, I review _way_ too much, maxing out multiple queues every day. The system doesn't take that into account, let alone the number of passed audits. All it cares about is how many you failed (not a percentage). The system essentially punishes those who review a lot.

Comment: @jhpratt Which is why I rarely review any more.

Comment: There was an audit the other day where in the question the OP had a hyperlink behind a couple seriously vulgar words, I was shocked that that was a test question - can't they use something else less offensive?

Comment: @dwirony Without providing a link here, so that a mod can fix it, that particular audit will probably be presented to other people. Without a link, a mod would have to go through your review/audit history to find it, which may be more work than they choose to do.

Comment: @dwirony There was a discussion about not using posts removed for being rude as audits and IIRC the last thing said was that they'd consider it but that still won't prevent you from occasionally having to deal with that sort of thing outside of audits.

Comment: The question itself has now been deleted. Nobody will get it as a review again

Comment: I wonder if the person who asked will know what happened.  I tagged the question as under discussion in meta shortly before it got deleted; which doesn't leave much time for the comment to've been seen before it all got wiped out.

Comment: @DanNeely The question got closed pretty quickly after the Meta question got posted so there's a decent chance they saw the notice saying why the question was off topic before the deletion.

Comment: @dwirony I had a particularly nasty audit from a couple of weeks ago that was the remnant of a troll attack targeting a certain user on this site. Apparently there was nothing really to be done other than what's already been covered [in this meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362493/nsfw-triage-review-audit)

Comment: @DanNeely There was a comment made when the question was asked on May 22 that indicated it was off topic. Someone then followed that up with a comment that they should just flout the rules instead, and that appears to have carried the day. I'm not sure how it escaped closure the first time around [Full timeline of the Q](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50459871/timeline)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You did the right thing; this question is off-topic, but unfortunately it had 8 upvotes and no downvotes or close votes, so was chosen as a 'known good' audit item. That is now rectified... the Meta Effect has been applied, clearly, and the question is also closed, so it will no longer be used as an audit.

Don't worry about one failed audit harming your review record; it takes a series of failures to incur a ban.