# Need better descriptions for why post was deleted in Audit

Tags: discussion, review-audits, low-quality-posts, disputed-review-audits, spam

Failed [this Audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/21673179). Which is fine, as I seem to fail them all the time lately. But the description of why the post was deleted covers all possible topics--I think inciting insurrection might be listed as one of the possible reasons for deletion...

But I have no idea which one of them. The text in the answer answers the question. The link goes to a website that's junk, but also answers the question, and appears to be no more junk than most other "how does the web work" websites.

So I'm honestly interested. Is it spam I'm missing, or some degree of specificity where the answer is actually incorrect?

EDIT: oh, so I really was posting not because I cared about the failure, but as a suggestion that "narrowing" down the reasons for the original deletion seemed like a good idea that would only improve review skills, instead of leaving me wondering each time. Just wanted to make sure that that point, from the title, wasn't lost.

Review Fail:
[image]

Page it links to:
[image]

Comment: "Which is fine, as I seem to fail them all the time lately."  That's...not fine at all.  Failing one very infrequently is fine, but if you're failing them a lot, that's a big problem.  Because it means you're reviewing incorrectly for reviews that the system *doesn't* already know how to handle, and you're doing it "all the time".

Comment: But yes, that does look like spam.  LQP isn't for evaluating the technical merits of posts.  A post being wrong isn't reason to delete it.

Comment: Yeah, I'll probably give up reviewing shortly. I suspect there's some degree of deep diving into questions I'm missing, or not willing to do as part of a "quick overview" review of questions and answers. This one I finally decided to drill deep into after failing and couldn't figure it out. So thought I'd suggest that we provide more specific reasons. As a list of 50 things from "not good", to "obusive" to "spam", doesn't seem to help frame up the mismatch.

Comment: @Servy so what aspect of it makes you say "it looks like spam"? I suspect that's the missing quirk in my quick evaluations.

Comment: The second paragraph is a copy of the text on the linked site but doesn't cite it correctly. That alone is enough reason to delete it.

Comment: @BDL yeah, that seems to be what folks claim most of the time. Someone says it's clearly spam, then someone says "well, it's not spam, it has a chunk of text copy and pasted, so that's plagiarism". I don't see plagiarism listed in the possible reasons for deletion. And I'm not personally going to spend the time to copy and paste every sentence into google, so that's why I'm asking. Reviewing  probably isn't for me, but this one made me interested. :-)

Comment: @CooperBuckingham If they're the author of the linked page, it's spam, if they're not, it's plagiarism.  Either merits a moderation action, and you said none was needed.

Comment: Yeah, I'm just not going to type every sentence of every answer into google. I totally think that's a valid thing for a bot to do, but it seems to go against the efficiency of crowd sourced quick reviews. But I still think that providing a more specific reason for why the answer was deleted, instead of having to have a discussion about it after the fact would help others.

Comment: @Cooper we don't expect your to type every sentence of every answer into Google. The answer linked to the page it was plagiarizing from/spamming. All you had to do was visit the link and you would realize that it definitely does not Look OK. At that point if you were unsure of what to do, you could skip or look for guidance on meta. Instead you said it Looks OK.

Comment: The second paragraph of a correct answer is copied from the third paragraph of a website with a further correct answer. Which is linked to in the post. I’m not personally going to do that type of in depth analysis to determine plageuirism. But I believe it still makes sense to provide a more specific reason for deletion in the audit. Otherwise you might as well just say “you failed” “there’s something wrong with the post, go post it on meta to find out what” :-)

Comment: I mean if you dont want to put forth the effort required to review... dont review. As for more information  if you dont understand why you failed an audit, the general course of action is to ask why on meta. That works for everyone else...

Comment: I agree. I think you’re missing the point. I’m suggesting that the reason for deletion be far more specific in the audit failed message in order to help reviewers. I don’t believe any working software engineer would put in the time to read every web page linked to in a review answer, but maybe that’s a small subset that can still be useful and once they find it out; provide that information more specifically, in order to prevent threads like these?

Comment: I think you're drastically overstating the amount of effort this would require to review correctly, and that (along with the fact that you "seem to fail them all the time lately") belies how truly little effort you think is expected of you when reviewing.

Comment: I think you have won the “I’m not going to read external websites” debate soundedly. But I’m posting here to suggest that the reason for deletion be more specific in in the audit fail message in order to provide more useful feedback and learning opportunities.

Comment: There is no reason "Reason For Deletion" recorded when a post is deleted, except in some very specific situations and I'm fairly certain that in these situations the system will provide an augmented audit failure message to that effect. The rest of the time such a reason would have to be inferred by the system, which is what you're supposed to do. So I don't think this request is practical, nor do I think that the end result would be more useful than the current system.

Comment: I’m suggesting that a more specific reason for deleting be recorded when the deleting happens. That seems reasonable right? Even y’all die hards can’t argue against specificity. As “all possible reasons” doesn’t feel useful. Especially considering that this one is apparently for plageurism; which isn’t listed as a possible reason.

Comment: But any 20k+ rep user can vote to delete answers for a variety of different reasons. What you're suggesting is that users must select a reason from a predefined set of reasons in a whole new dialog when voting to delete answers. That's a bit much. There's a whole lot of different possible solutions to the problem you're trying to solve, but it doesn't seem like you've done much research on the matter or have put much thought into what such a system might look like or the scope of the change required to satisfy the request.

Comment: I suggest that you might not be looking at the problem in actuality and are instead framing it in what has already been designed and implemented. Which is a very good way to keep the problem. :-)

Comment: @cooper so what I understand here is you basically want users to explain their delete votes? Because short of that, you can't really get the outcome you look for. And 5 users could delete a question with 5 different reasons. How do we determine which one is 'the correct one' to display as an audit? It seems that we'll require manual intervention to determine the reason, which isn't how audits are picked now :/

Comment: I'm just detailing the problems I see with your request. How else do you suggest the system present you with a deletion reason without requiring users to provide one when voting for deletion?

Comment: I would suggest that if 5 users have 5 different reasons for a delete vote, then there’s a bigger problem with the system. If we can’t quantify why a post is being removed from a site, that seems problematic in itself. But if there are 5 different reasons a post was marked to be deleted, I suppose archiving them all and displaying them all is better than nothing. But I would still suggest that without a clear reason, you end up with scenarios like this where reviews need meta discussions.

Comment: @Cooper what if all of the reasons used are applicable?

Comment: @CooperBuckingham people on meta have 20/20 vision. As we can all see it's an audit. When you're in the process of reviewing it's not as obvious sometimes.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks. Yvette. So it turns out we did know why it was deleted. And it turns out that of 4 or 5 people to claim they knew, and claim various obvious things, many were wrong, and got all up in arms about. I think it’s safe to say that there’s room for improvement there, and I hope more folks can manage to see outside the walls. :-)

Comment: @Cooper No one said it was anything other than either spam or plagiarism. Yvette confirmed that it was deleted as spam. Anyone with 10k could see it was deleted as either spam or rude/abusive due to the banner that is displayed on the deleted answer. I said that it was obvious that it was either spam or plagiarism when viewing it in the audit state if you followed the link (which is always an important thing to do in this queue). Yvette is the only one here that seems to think reviewing in this queue doesn't require looking for spam/plagiarism.

Comment: @TinyGiant I never said you don't look for spam. I explained what puts posts into the audit pool and spam is actually one of the reasons. So it's perfectly reasonable to judge something as spam. I stated plagiarism won't bump posts into the low quality review queue or the audit queue (usually)

Comment: @Yvette you said this isn't a good LQ audit, when it is actually a great LQ audit. Even Shog commented that it is a fine audit on your answer.

Comment: @TinyGiant there's no indication that it's spam. It was the sheer quantity of the posts by this user that caused it's deletion. The fact that it doesn't answer the question is another issue and has no bearing on why it was actually deleted. I'm dealing with what actually happened in this instance. It also wouldn't show up as spam for 10k users, only mods can see the flags on the post.

Comment: @Yvette there is absolutely an indication that it is either spam or plagiarism. Either warrants further investigation, or at the very least a flag.

Comment: Also notice that I said "Anyone with 10k could see it was deleted as **either** spam **or** rude/abusive due to the banner that is displayed on the deleted answer".

Comment: Looks like comments have started to get deleted, which causes the flow to be confusing, so just wanted to say I'm gonna move on, but hope that doesn't hurt anybody's feelings in if i don't respond any further. I hope something good comes out of it all. Thanks again.

Comment: @YvetteColomb Anytime you're in a review queue (in which one of your main purposes is to find spam) and you see answers clearly pushing people to go to some external resource (that's not a well know official resource for the topic at hand, like this random blog post) you should be highly suspicious of spam.  You shouldn't just immediately spam flag it, but you should have sirens going off in your head and be looking closely for other red flags.  In this case, more immediately pop up and it becomes clear that it's spam.  If you can't tell that this is spam *that's a problem* when reviewing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's two types of posts put into the audit pool. Those deleted as low quality and those deleted as spam (which includes posts deleted with a helpful spam flag).

The only reason this post was used as an audit, was because it was deleted as spam. (which includes posts deleted with a helpful spam flag)

[image]

That user account was deleted for spamming the Stack Overflow with links to that site. This really is something beyond the reviewers knowledge.

It is for this reason I have requested this in 
August:

[Can we have a mod tool to prevent posts from being selected for review audits, without invalidating flags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/313455/310756)

To be completely honest, I don't think this is obvious spam to a reviewer. The site looks legitimate when landing on it.  There's nothing to indicate the OP was the author of the linked page. There's many sites offering good information about programming. There's nothing obvious from this link, asking for money, to indicate it's a nefarious site.

Although some of the post is plagiarised from the link. Plagiarism would warrant a comment and/or mod flag, not deletion on the low quality review queue, as it currently stands.

Posts deleted for plagiarism are not added to the queue (it's automated). So to pass audits, the only way is to view a post as spam or low quality, not plagiarism.

Also, this is how I see the site - adblockers. Doesn't look spammy.

[image]

Update:

[This post would no longer make it to the review queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/377864/3956566).

> Additionally, I've added checks to ensure that only posts which were actually deleted by the system in response to spam flags are used for this purpose - this should avoid situations where posts deleted for other reasons (for instance, due to the destruction of their author's account) are used. Such posts are often offensive, confusing or otherwise misleading in the context of an audit, and thus relying on confirmed spam should avoid some unnecessary distress for reviewers here.

Comment: This audit has nothing to do with spam.  The review queue was LQ.  It was, that question doesn't need more crap answers.  He didn't look when rejecting a flag from a concerned SO user, that's why he failed the audit.  That spam is also often low quality is no accident.  Notable as well, having a mod turn spam into a link at meta is one way for spam to be successful.

Comment: Or maybe all audits should prompt the banner "_warning, this post was marked as potential spam by our system_"

Comment: @Cœur yeh. I think if we could pop some of these posts out of the audit pool it would be helpful.

Comment: It is definitely low-quality, @Hans - but audits for LQ review are drawn from spam, so it was the spam flag that put it in front of this reviewer, not the quality. Nevertheless, it makes an exceptionally fine audit for this queue.

Comment: @Shog9 the fact the answer didn't answer the question has no bearing on why it was deleted or was an audit. This is a flaw in the system. As we discussed in TL. I think there's issues around this.

Comment: I think it's a fine audit because it should've prompted an appropriate response in review, @Yvette. It's *probably* spam, it's arguably not even an answer, it's definitely low-quality and it definitely adds nothing useful to the question: there were numerous reasons why a reviewer should've chosen "Delete" or - if they were feeling particularly generous - "edit". There were no good reasons to choose "Looks OK", save for not having read the answer carefully and considered it in context. That makes it a good audit: it tests that the reviewer is paying attention.

Comment: I still read now the entire answer and don’t know what you’re talking about with it being low quality. It answers the question. Oddly and awkwardly. But I think there’s a huge disconnect somewhere with what paying attention gets. So just head’s up.

Comment: @CooperBuckingham Shog is referring to the fact that the answer doesn't answer the question. I'm referring to what put it in the audit pool.